# How to extract values from XML file?

Tags: python, xml, parsing, elementtree, xml.etree

I am struggling to parse a xml file using python.
Here is an extract of my xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
- <ns0:R xmlns="http//Pat" version="20200821_1009" stationCode="HYB" UnitName="ON" publicationTime="2020-08-21T09:09:25Z" transmissionLossProfilesVersion="20201500" ntProfilesVersion="202_161500" xmlns:ns0="ioa">
    - <Vol startDate="2009-01-01Z" xmlns="ioa">
        <EquitySplit party="ARC" equity="0" />
      </Vol>
    - <Vol startDate="2009-12-07Z" xmlns="ioa">
        <EquitySplit party="ARC" equity="100" />
      </Vol>
    - <Vol startDate="2010-04-05Z" xmlns="ioa">
        <EquitySplit party="Cena" equity="20" />
            <EquitySplit party="ARC" equity="80" />
        </Vol>
    - <Unit bmu="T_HEYM27" comment="Lower parking load" xmlns="ioa">
           + <Bafa="2010-05-21Z">
           + <Bafa="2020-05-22Z">
           - <Bafa="2020-05-23Z">
                  <V>44.000000</V>
                  <V>44.000000</V>
                  <V>44.000000</V>
                  <V>44.000000</V>
                  <V>44.000000</V>
                  <V>44.000000</V>
            + <Bafa="2020-08-24Z">
```

Hundreds of `Bafa` are following on my actual full xml file. They represent different dates and contain values (here the value is `44.000000`).
My goal is to extract all the bafa with all their values in a list of dataframe.

Like:

```
2010-05-23Z
44.000000
44.000000
44.000000
44.000000
44.000000
44.000000
2010-05-24Z
...
...
```

I have tried this code:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse("xmlfile.xml")
root = tree.getroot()

a = [elem.attrib for elem in root.iter()]
```

The variable `a` stocks well the bafa dates, but creates empty dictionnaries for the values.

Comment: Patrick, your XML has a namespace. You need to take it into account.

Comment: I have tried the below to take into account namespace but it is not working. Dictionnaries created in a are empty.
a = [elem.attrib for elem in root.iter('{http//Pat}V')]

Comment: Is the xml valid?  This looks wrong:`<Bafa="2010-05-21Z">`

Comment: This is not an XML document since it not well-formed. There appears to be symbols before nodes, unclosed tags, and incorrect use of attributes. Surprisingly it passed without error in `ET.parse()`!

Comment: If you can switch to the lxml library things are better; that library supports the same ElementTree API: https://lxml.de/

Comment: Your XML file looks like the result displayed by the tool. Please post your XML source file.